# How to set correctly another language than English for Apple Store (ionic app)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, app-store

The first time I uploaded this ionic app to the Apple Store it showed as language "english", since that I looked here and around the web and manage to add a localization file. Now my project says:

[image]

I upload the new version to itunes Connect but it stills shows English as the app language (It should be German)

my de.xliff file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2 http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core-1.2-strict.xsd">
  <file original="myApp/myApp-Info.plist" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
    <header>
      <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode" tool-name="Xcode" tool-version="8.1" build-num="8B62"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="CFBundleDisplayName">
        <source>${PRODUCT_NAME}</source>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="CFBundleName">
        <source>${PRODUCT_NAME}</source>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="CFBundleShortVersionString">
        <source>1.1.0</source>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
  <file original="myApp/Localizable.strings" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="de">
    <header>
      <tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode" tool-name="Xcode" tool-version="8.1" build-num="8B62"/>
    </header>
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="Load Error">
        <source>Load Error</source>
        <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="Loading...">
        <source>Loading...</source>
        <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="►">
        <source>►</source>
        <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="◄">
        <source>◄</source>
        <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your de.xliff file does not contain a single target language string. A translated XLIFF file should contain a `<target>` element for every translatable `<source>` element, like this:

```
  <trans-unit id="Load Error">
    <source>Load Error</source>
    <target>Ladungsfehler</target>
    <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
  </trans-unit>
  <trans-unit id="Loading...">
    <source>Loading...</source>
    <target>Laden...</target>
    <note>No comment provided by engineer.</note>
  </trans-unit>
```

Please do not use my translations in your app: they are most likely not correct, as Load can have many meanings. You should consider putting a note in that tells your translator what is meant by `Load Error` and `Loading...`.